# Configuring Java sendMail to work with button that already has a function

Tags: javascript, json, email

We have a scheduling system on our site.

We're trying to set it up so when someone clicks the button, along with the command the button already has, it will send an email through Mandrill.

Currently the button is under the class, `.bookingjs-form-button`.
Our question is, how can we specify the following java/jQuery to work with just the `.bookingjs-form-button`.  The system is embedded, we have access to everything but the HTML, which is why we can't simply do the following.

Thanks in advance!

#### HTML

```html
<form name="mail">
  <input type="button" value="Click!" onClick="sendMail()">
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
function sendMail() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
    data: {
      'key': 'YOUR_KEY',
      'message': {
        'from_email': 'YOUR_SENDER@example.com',
        'to': [{
          'email': 'YOUR_RECEIVER@example.com',
          'name': 'YOUR_RECEIVER_NAME',
          'type': 'to'
        }],
        'subject': 'title',
        'html': 'html can be used'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, but you can use it like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='send'>Send</div>
<script>
  $('#send').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
      data: {
        'key': 'YOUR_KEY',
        'message': {
          'from_email': 'YOUR_SENDER@example.com',
          'to': [{
          'email': 'YOUR_RECEIVER@example.com',
          'name': 'YOUR_RECEIVER_NAME',
          'type': 'to'
        }],
        'subject': 'title',
        'html': 'html can be used'
      }
    }
  });
 });
</script>
```